# Why is yaml_parse_file returning true?

Tags: php, yaml, pecl

For some reason when I run the `.php` script:

```
$s = yaml_parse_file("../config.yaml") || die("YAML file not found");
var_dump($s);
```

it returns:

> bool(true)

What on earth is going on? This has happened out of nowhere it was working fine for a week and I can't seem to fix it. I have installed using `pecl install yaml` and added `"extension=yaml.so"` to `php.ini`?

I have used online yaml regex testers and they return that it is okay. The format is (obviously with content):

```
title: 
email: hello@
logo: images/logo.png
download-file: .dmg
recaptcha:
  pub:
  priv:
meta:
  keywords: mac, osx
  description:
  ico: images/icon.ico
```

Comment: Read about PHP [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), get rid of `or die()` and do a proper error handling.

Comment: Yeah doing this poor error handling as just a reminder if I haven't uploaded the `.yaml` as part of building a 'template' website.

Comment: Nothing happens other than missing images if it is not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning the result of the boolean operation to `$s`, since the `||` operator has a higher precedence than the assignment. So it's being evaluated as follows:

```
$s = (yaml_parse_file("../config.yaml") || die("YAML file not found"));
```

This returns true, since the initial expression returns a "truthy" value.

If you wrap the assignment in brackets, it will work as you are expecting:

```
($s = yaml_parse_file("../config.yaml")) || die("YAML file not found");
...
```

See https://eval.in/960405

Comment: Or just use the `or` operator, which has lower precedence (even lower than assignment).

Comment: @Bytewave better forget about the stupid `or die()` part and do a proper error handling.

Comment: @axiac Can't say I disagree, but OP just wanted an answer to his question. Comments on best practices are comments.

Answer (score 1):

The code worked before, when it used to read:

```
$s = yaml_parse_file("../config.yaml") or die("YAML file not found");
```

You recently changed `or` with `||` (why?) without knowing that they are different operators and they have [different precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

`or` has the lowest precedence and the expression above is evaluated as:

```
($s = yaml_parse_file(...)) or die(...)
```

`||` has higher precedence than the assignment (`=`) and the expression posted in the question evaluates as:

```
 $s = (yaml_parse_file(...) || die(...))
```

To solve the issue, first you should forget about `or die()`. It is bad coding practice spread out by PHP tutorial more than 15 years ago. It's sad that many of them are still available on the web and teach the newbies how to throw a white page on the face of their visitors when an error happens.

`or die()` is useless. If `yaml_parse_file()` (or whatever function call you "handle" using it) returns `FALSE`, the next statement that attempts to use the result most probably will fail anyway. And you'll get a more or less descriptive error message in `php_errors.log`. That error message help you debug the code and identify and fix the errors. `or die` doesn't help with anything. It just hides the error under the carpet and tells the visitor what they can see by themselves: that your site doesn't work. But it doesn't tell you what was the error or how to fix it.